# Shape keys transfer and armature "rest pose"

Tags: animation, armature, shape-keys, properties

My question is quite complicated, so for clarity I will describe it the best that I can. I use a model in a Blender; it's rigged and posed(!) -  I also want to send it to Zbrush in current pose, do sculpting and then return the model to Blender, make a duplicate and transfer changes as shape key so that I can apply it onto the original model

At the moment, after this interaction, my model turns inside out, apparently because after exporting from Zbrush, the shape-key with the update is applied not to the current position that I chose, but to the Rest pose (to the position that the model returns to when we press alt+r/g)

My question: is Blender able to apply the shape key to the current pose and not to the Rest pose, like make updates lay down on top of everything and not beneath,change priority
super important thing to me,need really nerd look here >.<